# How to store strings into an array from a foreach loop?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

To start off, I've read the handful of questions here asking *similar* questions but nothing that I could take example of and implement properly into my code. I've got an array that hold a few thousand numbers, they're the names of a file in a directory. I need to run a MySQL Query that searches for those file names, but I need all the individual queries to be in another array.

Here's my code to grab the filenames:

```
$dir = "C:/Users/EyeCandy-Brian/Desktop/jobs";

$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));

function truncate(&$fcn) {
     $fcn = substr($fcn, 0, 6); // The original is '100100.dat', I only need the number
};

array_walk($files, "truncate");
```

The array looks like this:

```
2 => string '100100'
3 => string '100101'
4 => string '100102'
5 => string '100103'
// About 1,500+ Total
```

And here's my foreach loop with my declared variables:

```
$limit = 0; // This is for testing, stops after 5 iterations.
$qryArrNum = 2; // The index for the $files array, [0] & [1] were '.' & '..'
$count = 0; // Which index I want to store the string in, starting at [0]

$qry = array(); // I declare $qry as an array

foreach ($files as &$qry) {
    $qry[$count++] = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `sku` LIKE '%$files[$qryArrNum]%'";
    ++$qryArrNum;
    if (++$limit == 5) {
        break;
    };
};
```

Here's where it gets wild. When using `var_dump($qry);` I get `'1001S4'` which shouldn't be. Running `var_dump($files);` The first five strings of the array are:

```
2 => string 'S00100'
3 => string '1S0101'
4 => string '10S102'
5 => string '100S03'
6 => string '1001S4'
```

Then following that are the expected strings from the filenames:

```
7 => string '100105'
8 => string '100106'
9 => string '100107'
// On for 1,500+ again
```

So my question is, how do I get `$qry` to be an array that contains a string, each string being the MySQL Query containing a search for the first value from `$files`, and the next string in the `$qry` array will search for the next value from `$files`. Also, why are the first handful values in `$files` completely different than what's expected?

**NOTE:** I understand that running a thousand plus MySQL Queries sequentially will murder my server, I'll use `implode();` to combine them into one large query, I just need to figure this out initially.

Comment: You have a variable outside (`$qry`) that's the same in the foreach value. Why?

Comment: `foreach ($files as &$qry)` is what is messing you up. change it to `foreach ($files as $file)` then you can use `$qry[$file] = "SELECT * FROM...`

Comment: You seem to be overcomplicating things here.

Comment: Also `$qry[$count++] = ` is kinda pointless if you're going 0,1,2,3,4 etc, just use `$qry[] = ` and the index will automatically increment numerically.

Comment: @Scuzzy Oh my goodness, I swear I read over that a million times and it looked fine to me, I need more coffee. Thank you a ton. And I tried `$qry[]` initially but it threw an error, which I guessing is due to the `$files as $qry` part being incorrect.

Comment: @FirstOne I'm known around the office for exactly that.

Comment: "_part being incorrect_" Yep, you were trashing $qry with every iteration from the current value of the foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running multiple queries you could use the mysql find_in_set().
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set
Once you have your files, use implode to convert to a string

```
$tmp = implode(",",$files);
```

Your sql statement would be:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`sku`,'{$tmp}')>0";
```

This will return all the matching items

Comment: It also looks like he wants to break out of the loop after 5 queries if I am reading OP code correctly. If so, maybe add LIMIT 5 to the SQL query?

Comment: @CMiller the variable `$limit` is there strictly for testing purposes, in WAMP I have it stop at 5 so I don't have to wait forever for the loop to iterate thousands of times. It will be removed when I implement the imploding of the queries and push it live, thank you though!